# Extract values from json data with condition and add them in as new columns

Tags: python, json, pandas, algorithm, data-structures

I have a Pandas DataFrame with JSON data. I'd like to extract the most recent `year` and the corresponding `val` and add them in as new column.

Sample DataFrame:

```
data = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'],
    'json_data': [
        '{"year": [2000, 2001, 2002], "val": [10, 20, 30]}',
        '{"year": [2003, 2004, 2005], "val": [50, 60, 70]}',
        '{"year": [2006, 2007, 2008], "val": [80, 90, 85]}'
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Expected output:

New columns:

`Most Recent Year`
`Most Recent val`

For row with `id` 1, this would the year `2002` and val `30`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use a function to figure out the latest values from each JSON string and apply that to the dataframe. In your data it looks like the most recent values are the last ones, in which case you could simply use:

```py
def most_recent_values(row):
    dd = json.loads(row['json_data'])
    return (dd['year'][-1], dd['val'][-1])
```

If that's not the case, you'll have to find the index of the maximum value of the `(year, val)` tuple and use that:

```py
def most_recent_values(row):
    dd = json.loads(row['json_data'])
    return max(zip(dd['year'], dd['val']))
```

Then you can add the two new columns with [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```py
df[['Most Recent Year', 'Most Recent Val']] = df.apply(most_recent_values, axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

For your sample data, the result of both functions is the same:

```
   id     name                                          json_data  Most Recent Year  Most Recent Val
0   1    Alice  {"year": [2000, 2001, 2002], "val": [10, 20, 30]}              2002               30
1   2      Bob  {"year": [2003, 2004, 2005], "val": [50, 60, 70]}              2005               70
2   3  Charlie  {"year": [2006, 2007, 2008], "val": [80, 90, 85]}              2008               85
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `map`, `zip`, and `max`, the solution is straightforward.

```py
df[['Most Recent Year', 'Most Recent val']] = (
    df['json_data']
    .map(json.loads)
    .map(lambda d: list(zip(d['year'], d['val'])))
    .map(lambda tup: list(max(tup)))
    .tolist()
)
```

Result:

```
   id     name                                          json_data  Most Recent Year  Most Recent val
0   1    Alice  {"year": [2000, 2001, 2002], "val": [10, 20, 30]}              2002               30
1   2      Bob  {"year": [2003, 2004, 2005], "val": [50, 60, 70]}              2005               70
2   3  Charlie  {"year": [2006, 2007, 2008], "val": [80, 90, 85]}              2008               85
```

---

To understand what's going on, break it into steps:

```py
tuple_series = (df['json_data']
    .map(json.loads)
    .map(lambda d: list(zip(d['year'], d['val']))
)
```

That's a `Series` in which each value is a list-of-tuples:

```
0    [(2000, 10), (2001, 20), (2002, 30)]
1    [(2003, 50), (2004, 60), (2005, 70)]
2    [(2006, 80), (2007, 90), (2008, 85)]
```

Then find the `max` tuple in each list, and convert the whole result to lists-of-lists so the column assignment will work correctly.

(Note that in Python, tuples can be compared to each other, so `max` will work as expected. It compares the first items, then the second items only if necessary.)

```py
tuple_series.map(lambda tup: list(max(tup))).tolist()
```

Result:

```
[[2002, 30], [2005, 70], [2008, 85]]
```

---

Edit:

Here's what it looks like if you combine those `.map` calls into a single function:

```py
def most_recent(j):
    d = json.loads(j)
    year, val = max(zip(d['year'], d['val']))
    return [year, val]

df[['Most Recent Year', 'Most Recent val']] = df['json_data'].map(most_recent).tolist()
```

---

Edit: Just for fun, here's an even more succinct version, but it assumes that `year` always comes before `val` within the json, and that there are no other values in the json.

```py
df[['Most Recent Year', 'Most Recent val']] = (
    df['json_data']
    .map(lambda j: list(max(zip(*json.loads(j).values()))))
    .tolist()
)
```

Comment: I shamelessly borrowed your `max` code :P

Comment: Chaining multiple `map` is inefficient, better write a custom function and call it once ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom function to keep the most recent year then use `pd.concat` to get expected result:

```
import json

def most_recent(x):
    df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(x)).set_axis(['Most Recent Year',  'Most Recent val'], axis=1)
    return df.loc[df[['Most Recent Year']].idxmax()]

df1 = pd.concat([*df.pop('json_data').agg(most_recent)]).set_index(df.index)
out = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   id     name  Most Recent Year  Most Recent val
0   1    Alice              2002               30
1   2      Bob              2005               70
2   3  Charlie              2008               85
```